# How to prove the Chebyshev's inequality in this cases?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I only have the idea of the Chebyshev's inequality that said

$$P(|X-\mu|\geq a\sigma)\leq \frac{Var(X)}{a^2\sigma^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}$$

But, I have my doubts about this, is it possible to prove this with Chebyshev's inequality

$$P(|X-\mu|\leq a)\geq 1-\frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$$

$$P(|X-\mu|\leq a\sigma)\geq 1-\frac{1}{a^2}$$

(Sorry for my English in case something is not understandable)

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb P(|X-\mu| \le a) = 1 - \mathbb P(|X-\mu| > a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $a$ by $a\sigma/\sigma$ and use Chebychev. Follows directly from $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\ge y) =1 - \mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|<y)$